# Can I set VSCode as default editor for specific file type through extension?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am currently developing a VSCode extension in `javascript` for a specific type of files. I would like to add a functionality that when opening this file type, the extension will check if the default editor of the file type is VSCode and if not this message will appear:
[image]

And then if the user clicks on `Open with VSCode`, the extension will set VSCode as the default editor of this type of files.

I searched on the [VS Code API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api) but I didn't find something useful and I have no clue how I could do something like that.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You have to interact with the OS to set the defaults. For example - you can go in settings - apps - default apps to set the default apps for specific file types. So I think you cannot do it directly as it also requires admin privileges and you can try using automation or something like that to achieve this. I don't think anyone can provide a direct way or code to do what you mentioned.

Comment: I am afraid you are right but I won't market it as the correct answer yet just in case an other answer shows up! Thank you for your help.

Comment: "it also requires admin privileges" is not very likely to be true. Using which editor as default is just a user level setting, not a machine level setting.